# Why `textwidth` gives me the same effect as `linebreak`?

Tags: wrapping, textwidth

Could anybody explain, why `textwidth` works gives me the same effect as `linebreak`?

Example 1. If I type `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` several times, the last `aaa...` is wrapped to the next line. `linebreak` is off, so why does it happen?

```
set number
set wrap
set textwidth=79
set colorcolumn=+1
```

Example 2. Everything works as I expect it. When my reach the right side of screen, only a part of the last `aaaaaaaaaaaaaa` is wrapped.

```
set number
set wrap
set colorcolumn=+1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`:h 'linebreak'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27linebreak%27) has the following:

> Unlike `'wrapmargin'` and `'textwidth'`, this does not insert `<EOL>`s in the file, it only affects the way the file is displayed, not its contents.

But with [`:h 'textwidth'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27textwidth%27), a longer line will break with `<EOL>` after whitespace to get that width.